# I am working with static data,does my application needs to create database?

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite

i am working with an greeting card application in which all the things are static and user have to just select greetings.
so suggest me how to work with it there is 3 options i have like:
1)put text file in asset folder which is having all the data
2)database
3)string-array

database should include 
id
name
image
title
greeting
textstyle
textsize
frames
--but this will take too much memory allocation because there are 20 greetings. 
any kind of suggestions are valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to insert image as blob into database, because it requires to much memory, please keep the image path name, retrieve it from database and load the image.
Keep the greetings image in application database directory...
This is the suggestion to avoiding OutOfMemory exception. Try to load one by one.
And before loading the image into memory, always keep one thing in your mind that the image should not be too much large, if it is large then compress it and then load..

Comment: yes i am saving only the name of the image which are in drawable folder.

Comment: it is good idea to compress the image. but is there any need to work with database?

Comment: At first make a directory in your cuurent project database directory and copy all image file from your source folder to your database directory folder. If you need to save any other information, have to handle database.